# Trigger a "click" action on an image via text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, external, materialize

I couldn't find a direct answer on here for my inquiry, so hopefully one of the awesome folks on here can help! :)

I'm using MaterializeCSS. They have a class called "materialboxed" that you can attach to an element if you want to enlarge it. (Great for images, as in this case)

What I need to try to do is find a way to have a text link (Click to enlarge) trigger a "click" event on the image, hopefully activating the class and enlarging the image.

**Text link:** `<a href="">Click to enlarge</a>`
**Image:** `<img src="yourimage" class="materialboxed" />`

** MaterializeCSS is still in infancy and not well documented yet, so no answers there. And no, unfortunately there is no getting around using Materialize.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using normal JS.
You need to add an id to the image and then call a click event on it.

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('img').click()">Click to enlarge</a>
<img src="yourimage" class="materialboxed" id="img" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Although I had to remove the "href" altogether as it was causing the image to close immediately and jump to the top of the page ;) Thanks to everybody, you all rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='javascript:enlarge()'>Click to enlarge</a>
<img src="image.png" id='image' height="200px" class="materialboxed" />
<script>
    function enlarge() {
        document.getElementById('image').height =  400;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with MaterializeCSS, but from what I see, the images that have the `materialboxed` class has set up a `.click()` event.

So you can call a `click()` event on the image when someone clicks the "Click to enlarge" text.

Example in jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){          //Your <a href="">Click to Enlarge</a> tag
    $(".materialboxed").click();  //Your <img class='materialboxed'> tag
});
```